# Allow spaces in EMail validator in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

Im using email validator package on flutter to validate the email for login. I have one issue with this package that I want to allow spaces in the email when the user sign in because Im gonna trim the text anyway so I dont want it to show error when there is Spaces at the end.

```
 child: TextFormField(
            keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
            controller: emailController,
            cursorColor: Colors.white,
            textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
            decoration:   const InputDecoration(labelText: 'Email'),
            autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction,
            validator: (email) =>
            email != null && !EmailValidator.validate(email)
            ? 'Enter a valid Email' : null,
```

```
try {
      await _auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
        email: emailController.text.trim(),
        password: passwordController.text.trim(),
      );
```

Anyone knows how to do it or if there is a better way than using this package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use any package for validating email you can simply do it with `RegExp` like below in this space is allows and then you can trim it where ever you want to use

```
validator: (value) {
    bool emailValid = RegExp(r"^[a-zA-Z0-9.a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+-/=?^_`{|}~]+@[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[a-zA-Z]+").hasMatch(value!);
    if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
        return 'Please Enter Email Address';
    }else if (emailValid == false){
        return 'Please Enter Valid Email Address';
    }
   return null;
},
```

Let me know if you have any questions. Thanks

Comment: Thanks! I do prefer not to use any package to thank you for your suggestion

Comment: No, please don't use this so-called "regex email validation".

I can think of a few email addresses that are perfectly valid that do not match that regex. When you want to validate an email address, please do not use a hand-rolled (or even copy-n-pasted) regex.

Instead, use https://pub.dev/packages/email_validator which properly implements the RFC822 (et. seq.) address according to the rules in the RFC.

(Jokingly...) Or, cut-n-paste this one (and only this one): http://www.ex-parrot.com/~pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html. Don't forget to remove the newlines from that 1400-char monster. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can trim email first then you can check for validation.

```
 validator: (email) {
            if(email != null) {
                email = email.trim();
      (!EmailValidator.validate(email))
            ? 'Enter a valid Email' : null,
             }  
         return null;  

 }
```

Answer (score 1):

best practice to use TextFormField validation is to not to allow user to put irrelevant data

```
TextFormField(
                controller: _etcEmail,
                keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
               inputFormatter: [
                   // FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(RegExp(r"^[a-zA-Z0-9.a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+-/=?^_`{|}~]+@[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[a-zA-Z]+")),
                  // FilteringTextInputFormatter.deny(RegExp(r" ")),               
                   FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(RegExp(r" ")),

               ],
                hintText: 'Email',
                validator: (value) {
                  if (value!.isEmpty) {
                    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
                        backgroundColor: Colors.pinkAccent,
                        behavior: SnackBarBehavior.floating,
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                        content: (Text('Email Field is Required'))));
                  }
                },
                read: false,
              )
```